# ngdialog not update table after create new item

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, ng-dialog

I'm using AngularJS and have the following problem with ngdialog.

I have a function that opens a dialog and then saving dialog form elements which are then displayed in a table.

The table is updated without reloading the page, but to reopen the dialog goes with previous data.

I want to add a new item without reloading the page. Now I do, but I have to reload the page because when recreating another I get with the new data from the previous dialog

```js
var app = angular.module('AlarmsAddOn', ['ngTable', 'ngDialog'])

    app.controller('AlarmsAddOnCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter, ngTableParams, datas, ngDialog, tags, tagIndex, $timeout){

        var self=this;
        //initializing $scope
        $scope.data=datas;
        $scope.tagss=tags;
        $scope.tagIndex=tagIndex;

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10,
                filter: {
                    message: ''
                },
                sorting: {
                    tag_id: 'asc'
                }
            },
            {
                total: $scope.data.length,
                counts:[],
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                        $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) :
                        $scope.data;

                    params.total(orderedData.length);
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                }

            });
        //edit tag settings
        self.edit_addon = function(key){
            $http.post('/', key).then(function(results){
                if (results.status==201)
                {
                    $scope.typemsg="alert alert-success";
                    $scope.msgmsg = "The tag settings has been updated. The new Trigger Value is: "+key.value;
                    $scope.alertmsg = false;
                    $timeout(function () { $scope.alertmsg = true; }, 2000);
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.typemsg="alert alert-danger";
                    $scope.msgmsg = "Server Error";
                    $scope.alertmsg = false;
                    $timeout(function () { $scope.alertmsg = true; }, 2000);
                }
            });
        };
        //delete tag settings
        self.delete_addon = function(key){
            if(confirm("Are you sure to remove the tag settings")){
                var url='/'+key.tag_id+'/'+key.trigger;
                $http.delete(url).then(function (results) {
                    console.log(results);
                    if (results.status==200)
                    {
                        for(var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
                        {
                            if($scope.data[i].tag_id == key.tag_id && $scope.data[i].trigger == key.trigger)
                            {
                                var p=i;
                            }
                        }
                        $scope.data.splice(p,1);
                        $scope.tableParams.reload();

                        $scope.typemsg="alert alert-success";
                        $scope.msgmsg = "The tag settings of "+key.tag_name+" has been deleted";
                        $scope.alertmsg = false;
                        $timeout(function () { $scope.alertmsg = true; }, 2000)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $scope.typemsg="alert alert-danger";
                        $scope.msgmsg = "Server Error";
                        $scope.alertmsg = false;
                        $timeout(function () { $scope.alertmsg = true; }, 2000);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        //create new tag settings
        self.savetag = function () {
            $scope.tag=self.tag;
            $http.post('/', $scope.tag).then(function (results) {
                if (results.status==201)
                {
                   $scope.data.unshift(self.tag);
                   $scope.tableParams.reload();
                 // window.location.reload();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            });

          ngDialog.close();

        };
        //show form to add new tag settings
        self.insert_modal_windows_addon = function()
        {
            ngDialog.open({ template: '/assets/insert.html', controller: 'AlarmsAddOnCtrl', scope: $scope, cache: false});
        };

    });
```

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Add New Tag</h3>

<form name="tag_form" ng-submit="AOC.savetag()" >

    <select class="form-control" name="tagid" placeholder="Tag Id"  ng-model="AOC.tag.tag_id">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Tag Name</option>
        <option ng-repeat="k in tagss" value="{{k}}">{{tagIndex[k]}}</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" name="tagtriggertype" placeholder="Trigger Type" ng-model="AOC.tag.trigger" style="margin:20px auto;">
        <option value="" disabled selected style="color:#333;">Trigger Type</option>
        <option value="hight">hight</option>
        <option value="low">low</option>
    </select>

    <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="tagtriggervalue" placeholder="Trigger Value" ng-model="AOC.tag.value", style="margin:20px auto;"/>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>
        Submit
    </button>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I never saw an ng-dialog="" anywhere in your HTML...was this a mistake?

Comment: I open de ngdialog calling the function insert_modal_windows_addon. In js: self.insert_modal_windows_addon = function()
        {
            ngDialog.open({ template: '/assets/insert.html', controller: 'AlarmsAddOnCtrl', scope: $scope, cache: false});
        };

Comment: I have no problems opening the dialog. The problem is that when I return to open exits with previous data

Comment: problem solved. delete var before load ngDialog